# Automated SP_WhoIsActive SQL Activity Capturing Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, jobs, sp-whoisactive

I have an SQL Agent Job on a production server that keeps failing with the below messages. It is supposed to be capturing SQL Server activity using the [`SP_WHOISACTIVE`](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) stored proc, at regularly scheduled intervals.

> Executed as user:  Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate
>   or other SET operation. [SQLSTATE 01003] (Message 8153)
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation. [SQLSTATE 01003] (Message 8153)
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation. [SQLSTATE 01003] (Message 8153)
>
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_WhoIsActive'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'monitoring.WhoIsActive'. The duplicate key
>   value is (Jan 20 2017  8:25AM, 109). [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 2627)
>
> The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).
>
> The step failed.

Any idea what may be causing this?

What steps should I follow to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Automate capturing SQL Server activity with `SP_WHOISACTIVE` and `SP_WHO2` via a SQL Agent job

> **Any idea what may be causing this?**

Obviously your current process has an issue trying to insert duplicate data on a table with a constraint that doesn't allow such data to be duplicated where the value is `Jan 20 2017 8:25AM, 109` per the defined `PK_WhoIsActive` Primary Key.

> **What steps should I follow to fix this error?**

I've copied the logic I've used with success on this sort of task below. I run the create table logic once (for both) but save it to a commented out or skipped SQL Agent step for future reference only.

I shared both the `SP_WHOISACTIVE` and the `SP_WHO2` capturing methods and logic below but be sure you're on the DB to run the `SP_WHO2` processes as it's logic is implicit. Be sure to specify the table and DB Names in the `SP_WHOISACTIVE` processes since its logic is explicit.

### SP_WhoIsActive Table Capturing

**Create Table**

```
DECLARE @destination_table VARCHAR(4000);

SET @destination_table = 'WhoIsActive_Cap';

DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(4000);

EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @get_transaction_info = 1
    ,@get_plans = 1
    ,@return_schema = 1
    ,@schema = @schema OUTPUT;

SET @schema = REPLACE(@schema, '<table_name>', @destination_table);

PRINT @schema

EXEC (@schema);
```

**Capture to Table**

```
SET @destination_table = '[<DB_Name>].dbo.WhoIsActive_Cap'

EXEC Master.dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @get_transaction_info = 1
    ,@get_plans = 1
    ,@destination_table = @destination_table;

-- remove records older than 7 days but adjust accordingly for your needs
DELETE
FROM [<DB_Name>].dbo.WhoIsActive_Cap
WHERE collection_time < dateadd(dd, -7, getdate())
```

---

### SP_WHO2 Table Capturing

**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.who2cap (
    SPID INT
    ,[Status] VARCHAR(100)
    ,[Login] VARCHAR(100)
    ,HostName VARCHAR(50)
    ,BlkBy VARCHAR(10)
    ,DBName VARCHAR(255)
    ,Command VARCHAR(500)
    ,CPUTime INT
    ,DiskIO INT
    ,LastBatch VARCHAR(20)
    ,ProgramName VARCHAR(500)
    ,SPID2 INT
    ,REQUESTID INT
    )
```

**Capture to Table**

```
CREATE TABLE #who2cap (
    SPID INT
    ,[Status] VARCHAR(100)
    ,[Login] VARCHAR(100)
    ,HostName VARCHAR(50)
    ,BlkBy VARCHAR(10)
    ,DBName VARCHAR(255)
    ,Command VARCHAR(500)
    ,CPUTime INT
    ,DiskIO INT
    ,LastBatch VARCHAR(20)
    ,ProgramName VARCHAR(500)
    ,SPID2 INT
    ,REQUESTID INT
    )

INSERT #who2cap
EXEC sp_who2

-- remove old entries (currently set to 3 weeks)
DELETE
FROM dbo.who2cap
WHERE logdt < dateadd(dd, - 21, getdate())

INSERT INTO dbo.who2cap
SELECT getdate()
    ,*
FROM #who2cap

DROP TABLE #who2cap
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears from the Primary Key name that you are running Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive and storing the result in a table.

If that is the case, the warnings are normal and caused by the options you set when calling sp_WhoIsActive. The Primary Key violation is what is causing the job to fail.

Take a look at the definition of the primary key.

I believe you will find that the Primay Key needs to be changed in order to insure uniqueness.

In my implementations for this I leave the table as a heap and do not define a primary key on this table. I only keep a few days of data in the table and do not use it for replication.

Here is an article on how to implement it:
[Brent Ozar Implementation of sp_WhoIsActive](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/)